# Django fastcgi command

Tags: python, django, bash, nginx, fastcgi

If I log in as user `www-data` and run this command it works:

```
python /var/www/ssrc/jvwf/manage.py runfcgi --settings=spzr.settings-dev \\
method=prefork socket=/tmp/www/spzr.socket pidfile=/tmp/www/spzr.pid \\
minspare=4 maxspare=8 maxchildren=128 maxrequests=65535 daemonize=false
```

However when I run it from `root`, in the following way (to be run as `www-data`):

```
exec /bin/su -c "python /var/www/ssrc/jvwf/manage.py runfcgi \\
--settings=spzr.settings-dev --pythonpath=/var/www/ssrc/jvwf \\
method=prefork socket=/tmp/www/spzr.socket pidfile=/tmp/www/spzr.pid \\
minspare=4 maxspare=8 maxchildren=128 maxrequests=65535 \\
daemonize=false" - www-data
```

it does not work.

Practically the second command is just:

```
exec /bin/su -c "FIRST_COMMAND" - www-data
```

The issue is that it cannot properly import the an intermediate settings file imported from within the settings file passed. I guess it's an ENV (or *path*) issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

(The `\\` above are line separators for display purposes, I'm using *one* liners in reality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one difference would be that when using su with the - option it cds to the home directory automatically. try adding a cd in front of your command:

```
exec /bin/su -c "cd /var/www/ssrc/...; python ..." - www-data
```

otherwise: what error messages do you get?

Comment: It worked. I had `chdir /var/www/ssrc/jvwf` further up in the upstart script, but I believe it was done for `root` and not for `www-data`. Thanks!